# Finding Prefix as Suffix in a string

Tags: c, string

I already posted this question but I'm still struggling to get it properly working. Dreamlax tried to help me out by giving the following steps -

- starting with `n = 1`, Take the first n characters from the string.
- Compare it to the last n characters from the string
- Do they match?

  - If yes, print out the first n characters as the suffix and stop processing.
  - If no, increment n and try again. Try until n is in the middle of the string.

Here's my code which doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    int i, T, flag, j, k, len = 0, n;
    char W[20], X[20], A[20], B[20];
    scanf("%d", &T);
    for (i = 0; i < T; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", W);
        for (len = 0; W[len] != '\0'; len++)
            X[len] = W[len];
        X[len] = '\0';
        len--;
        n = 1;
        while (n < len / 2)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                A[k] = W[k];
            for (k = 0, j = len - n; W[j] != '\0'; j++, k++)
                B[k] = W[j];
            if (!strcmp(A, B))
            {
                printf("YES\n");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
        printf("NO\n");
    }
}
```

Help me in pin pointing the error please.

Comment: It is called a palindrome

Comment: You should null-terminate your auxliary strings `A` and `B`. Also, the `break` will break out of the `while` loop, printing possible both yes and no.

Comment: No, not a palindrome.

Comment: Here is the exact question. -A word is nice if it contains the same string as a proper prefix as well as a proper suffix. A proper prefix or suffix cannot be a long as the word itself.

e.g.
manama is nice because it contains ma as a proper prefix as well as a proper suffix.
panama is not a nice word.

Find out if a word is nice or not. 

INPUT
The first line of input contains T, the number of test cases. T test cases follow. Each test case contains a single word W.

Comment: Can you please explain what error you are currently experiencing(and if its compile/runtime what line is causing it). Thanks

Comment: Logical error. prefix is not being identified whether it is present as a suffix in the same string.

Comment: for start, both `X[20]` and `flag` are unused and the return type for `main()` should be `int` not `void`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things going on in your code:

- You should null-terminate your auxiliary strings `A` and `B`. Alternatively, yopu could compare just then `n` first characters with `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`.
- `strcmp` is a comparison function. It returns zero if the strings match. (Comparison function means it can be used in sorting to determine whether a string is lexically greater or smaller than another string. The nomenclature for such functions is to return a negative number for lexically smaller, a positive number for lexically greater and zero means equality.)
- You don't use the auxiliary string `X` excapt to find the length. You can easily find the length of a string with `strlen`, which, like `strcmp`, is declared in `<string.h>`
- The calculation of your index for the suffix is off. Your length `len` is one less than the actual length and `W[len]` is the last character. Don't subtract one from your length.

Here's your code, refactored into a function, so that input and program logic are separated as they ought to be:

```
int is_nice(const char *W)
{
    char A[20], B[20];
    int len = strlen(W);
    int j, k, n = 1;

    while (n < len / 2) {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) A[k] = W[k];
        A[k] = '\0';

        for (k = 0, j = len - n; W[j] != '\0'; j++, k++) B[k] = W[j];
        B[k] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(A, B) == 0) return 1;
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above, I've said that you could use `strncmp` to compare ony a certain number of characters in the string. If you think about it, you can omit the auxiliary strings `A` and `B` and compare just slices of your original string:

```
int is_nice(const char *W)
{
    int len = strlen(W);
    int n = 1;

    while (n < len / 2) {
        if (strncmp(W, W + len - n, n) == 0) return 1;
        n++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This saves a lot of copying, some temporary variables and has one other significant benefit: Because the code doesn't have to guess a maximum size for the auxiliary buffers, it now works for strings of any size.

Answer (score 1):

You have three errors in your code.

The first is when you compute the length of the input string. Subtracting 1 from `len` after the loop is not necessary (simulate this loop for a small `n` to see why).

In this line:

```
if (!strcmp(A, B))
```

you are comparing non null-terminated strings which is undefined behavior. You should either terminate strings `A` and `B` or use `strncmp(A, B, n)` to compare at most `n` characters.

The third error is a logical error. If a string is "nice", your program will output both `YES` and `NO`. But this one should be easy to fix.